# How to join friend's game in Crackdown 2

Tags: crackdown-2, xbox-360

How do I specifically join my friend's game in Crackdown 2? I fire it up and it tells me that I have a friend online hosting a game but if I click 'join' on the main menu it shows 'searching for best game' and then I'm playing with strangers.

The left bumper opens up the xbox overlay friends menu and there's no option to join his game there - only 'invite to party' which I guess does something else? His game might already be full I suppose but I can't tell.

Do I have to message him and get him to invite me? Seems odd there'd be a different workflow for friends games.

Thanks. This is probably a stupid question but I've never played online with XBox live much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't played the game yet, but your friend should be able to throw you an invite to his game through his own friends menu. Joining a party means you will create a group for you both (to chat in together (though you can set the chat to use the game chat also) and if you are the leader of the group, you can also choose to just send a game invite to the party, which will invite everyone in it to play. Details on the party system can be found [here](http://support.xbox.com/support/en/us/nxe/xboxlive/xboxlivecommunity/Parties/partyparticipant.aspx).

Comment: OK, thanks. Would he keep playing, though - if I invite him to a party will that pull him out of his game? The game says you can start your local game so that friends only can join so I assumed I could just drop in and say hi rather than prompting him to invite me. Thanks for the link - I'll keep reading that. (I haven't seen the guy in ages so it was more to say hi rather than actually play Crackdown with him, but I didn't want to ruin his game! I'll facebook him, that's safer :-) )

Comment: You can safely invite him to a party without pulling him out of the game. Partying is separate from gaming. You can party without playing any game at all.

Comment: Thanks. Reading elsewhere it looks like the way is to get invited, so it sounds like I'd have to invite him to a party then ask him to invite me.